# Unity: проблема с Touch на мобильных устройствах

Tags: unity3d

Я делаю мобильную игру и у меня появился вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на экран совершались определенные действия, например выстрел? у меня есть две кнопки для перемещения вниз и вверх а стреляю я через такую вот проверку:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) { 
Fire(); 
}
```

Но проблема в том, что выстрелы происходят даже когда я нажимаю на кнопку перемещения, а этого я не хочу. Т.е когда я нажимаю на кнопку "вверх", он начинает идти вверх и одновременно стрелять. А я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "вверх" игрок не стрелял, а если нажать вверх и еще на любое другое место тыкнуть, то уже мог стрелять в движении. 
Т.е игрок должен уметь стрелять при нажатии на практическую любую поверхность экрана (кроме опредленных кнопок, например пауза или кнопки перемещения)
Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Ну тип самый простой вариант, делаешь кнопку и выкручиваешь альфа канал в 0, делаешь на весь экран, а сверху делаешь другие кнопки. Профит.

Comment: ого изи изи бризи!) спасибо! ты гений!